# Error with git push

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, github

I have been trying to learn to use git and I just got stucked.

I am creating rails app and I tried to push some changes to Github and got this message from command line:

```
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@github.com:username/projectname.git'
hint: Updates were rejected because a pushed branch tip is behind its remote
hint: counterpart. If you did not intend to push that branch, you may want to
hint: specify branches to push or set the 'push.default' configuration variable
hint: to 'simple', 'current' or 'upstream' to push only the current branch.
```

Do you have any tips what might be wrong and what should I do?

Thank you.

Comment: " Updates were rejected because a pushed branch tip is behind its remote hint: counterpart." Does pulling the most recent version not work?

Comment: overwrite the remote with  git push -f origin <your-branch-name>

Comment: @Sandhu had poor advice IMO. You should understand what that does. In practice, you almost never want to do what use git push -f. The correct process would have been to do `git pull` followed by `git push`.

Comment: Agreed; `git push -f` is almost always a terrible idea unless you know *exactly* what you're doing and that it's safe to do so.

Comment: @max please your comment on answer sheet please so another person that come after will know the best answer. Just saying :)